# Pusher Auth value for subscription to private-channel has invalid format 'key:signature' (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pusher

Pusher worked, but stopped. The .env settings are 100% correct. Please tell me how to debug this? Also, I tried to make new Puser app

```
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected with new socket ID 126791.4368004
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":":88536630b30af895eb4ac1fcab4af7fcac1fbce3883074b00aa47cfc873c9362","channel":"private-user.1971"}}
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher:error","data":{"code":null,"message":"Auth value for subscription to private-user.1971 is invalid: should be of format 'key:signature'"}}
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Auth value for subscription to private-user.1971 is invalid: should be of format 'key:signature'"}}}
```

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=902144
PUSHER_APP_KEY=0dd4fc93384fc94b5d6b
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=*****************
```

```
var pusher = new Pusher('0dd4fc93384fc94b5d6b', {
    cluster: 'eu',
    forceTLS: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
             'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    }
});
```

```
class PusherController extends Controller
{
    public $pusher;

    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->pusher = new Pusher(env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'), env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'), env('PUSHER_APP_ID'));
    }

    public function auth(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return $this->pusher->socket_auth($request->get('channel_name'), $request->get('socket_id'));
        } else {
            return Response::make('Forbidden', 403);
        }
    }
}
```

Broadcasting.php:

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'eu',
                'useTLS' => true
            ],
        ],
```

Everything worked, but at some point it stopped. I'm desperate :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `env(...)` outside of config files. Use the `config(...)` with reference to the file and key you need. Example: `config('broadcasting.pusher.key')`

If you cache the configuration the `.env` file does not get loaded which means `env(...)` returns `null` for everything.

Sounds like you cached your configuration. You can test this theory by clearing the configuration cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

If it starts working again that was your issue.

> "If you execute the `config:cache` command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within your configuration files. Once the configuration has been cached, the `.env` file will not be loaded and all calls to the `env` function will return `null`."

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Configuration - Configuration Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#configuration-caching)